# Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service with Identity framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Looking at [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x), I downloaded the [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/windows-service/sample) and got it to work fine.

How would I add ASP.NET Core Identity  to this sample window service ? it seems using a windows service is the recommended way to host an ASP.NET Core app on Windows but I can't find any information on adding Identity ..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IT's not as simple as just adding it. I would suggest, you create a new projekt (from template) with identity and then migrate those implementations to your project.

In core 2.1, you could add a library with identity and yous scaffold the pages you need to edit. [Adding Identity in core 2.1](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/add-identity-ui-asp-net-core-2-1-application/)